# Can't insert Json arry into PostgreSQL because left bracket is missing error

Tags: postgresql

I have the following Json array and i want to store them into PostgreSQL custom type:

```
 ARRAY['{"jahr":2014,"monat":18.01},{"jahr":2020,"monat":21.54}']::"Portfolio".t_finanzierungenjson[]
```

But if i run my PrepareStatement i got the following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: faulty record constant:
> Detail: left bracket missing.

So what i missing ? Is the json array not correct ?

My custom type is just json[]

Comment: If your `t_finanzierungenjson` is `json[]`, then the `t_finanzierungenjson[]` that the array is  declared as will be `json[][]`. You'll want to strip off one of them.

Comment: Using `json[]` never made sense to me. Why mix native arrays with JSON if you can simply store a json array in a `json`? (or better `jsonb`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name maybe to avoid a `check` constraint with `jsonb_typeof(col) = 'array'`. But I agree with the general point!

Comment: @Bergi: a one time constraint definition seems to be a small price to pay compared to the hassle for each and every usage of such a column. An now that we have JSON path expressions, using a json array is much easier to query then an array of jsons

Comment: I guess some single quotes are missing. ```ARRAY['{"jahr":2014,"monat":18.01}', '{"jahr":2020,"monat":21.54}']:: ...```

Comment: Why can't I just save a JSON array from Java 1: 1 in PostgreSQL? When I read it out later, it also has the flat format so that I can process it directly in Javascript